# Saving Sub Class Models on TF 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a Sub-Class Retinanet model for Object detection. Now I want to save this model so that I can send it to someone who does not have access to model architecture, in case of Sequential model we just save the model as ".h5" file and we can send it to anyone we want. Is there any such. thing for custom models in TF 2.x? The code snippet for the custom class model is as follows:

```
def get_backbone():
    """Builds ResNet50 with pre-trained imagenet weights"""
    backbone = keras.applications.ResNet50(
        include_top=False, input_shape=[None, None, 3]
    )
    c3_output, c4_output, c5_output = [
        backbone.get_layer(layer_name).output
        for layer_name in ["conv3_block4_out", "conv4_block6_out", "conv5_block3_out"]
    ]
    return keras.Model(
        inputs=[backbone.inputs], outputs=[c3_output, c4_output, c5_output]
    )

class FeaturePyramid(keras.layers.Layer):
    """Builds the Feature Pyramid with the feature maps from the backbone.

    Attributes:
      num_classes: Number of classes in the dataset.
      backbone: The backbone to build the feature pyramid from.
        Currently supports ResNet50 only.
    """

    def __init__(self, backbone=None, **kwargs):
        super(FeaturePyramid, self).__init__(name="FeaturePyramid", **kwargs)
        self.backbone = backbone if backbone else get_backbone()
        self.conv_c3_1x1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 1, 1, "same")
        self.conv_c4_1x1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 1, 1, "same")
        self.conv_c5_1x1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 1, 1, "same")
        self.conv_c3_3x3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 1, "same")
        self.conv_c4_3x3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 1, "same")
        self.conv_c5_3x3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 1, "same")
        self.conv_c6_3x3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 2, "same")
        self.conv_c7_3x3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 2, "same")
        self.upsample_2x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(2)

    def call(self, images, training=False):
        c3_output, c4_output, c5_output = self.backbone(images, training=training)
        p3_output = self.conv_c3_1x1(c3_output)
        p4_output = self.conv_c4_1x1(c4_output)
        p5_output = self.conv_c5_1x1(c5_output)
        p4_output = p4_output + self.upsample_2x(p5_output)
        p3_output = p3_output + self.upsample_2x(p4_output)
        p3_output = self.conv_c3_3x3(p3_output)
        p4_output = self.conv_c4_3x3(p4_output)
        p5_output = self.conv_c5_3x3(p5_output)
        p6_output = self.conv_c6_3x3(c5_output)
        p7_output = self.conv_c7_3x3(tf.nn.relu(p6_output))
        return p3_output, p4_output, p5_output, p6_output, p7_output
def build_head(output_filters, bias_init):
    """Builds the class/box predictions head.

    Arguments:
      output_filters: Number of convolution filters in the final layer.
      bias_init: Bias Initializer for the final convolution layer.

    Returns:
      A keras sequential model representing either the classification
        or the box regression head depending on `output_filters`.
    """
    head = keras.Sequential([keras.Input(shape=[None, None, 256])])
    kernel_init = tf.initializers.RandomNormal(0.0, 0.01)
    for _ in range(4):
        head.add(
            keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, padding="same", kernel_initializer=kernel_init)
        )
        head.add(keras.layers.ReLU())
    head.add(
        keras.layers.Conv2D(
            output_filters,
            3,
            1,
            padding="same",
            kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
            bias_initializer=bias_init,
        )
    )
    return head
class RetinaNet(keras.Model):
    """A subclassed Keras model implementing the RetinaNet architecture.

    Attributes:
      num_classes: Number of classes in the dataset.
      backbone: The backbone to build the feature pyramid from.
        Currently supports ResNet50 only.
    """

    def __init__(self, num_classes, backbone=None, **kwargs):
        super(RetinaNet, self).__init__(name="RetinaNet", **kwargs)
        self.fpn = FeaturePyramid(backbone)
        self.num_classes = num_classes

        prior_probability = tf.constant_initializer(-np.log((1 - 0.01) / 0.01))
        self.cls_head = build_head(9 * num_classes, prior_probability)
        self.box_head = build_head(9 * 4, "zeros")

    def call(self, image, training=False):
        features = self.fpn(image, training=training)
        N = tf.shape(image)[0]
        cls_outputs = []
        box_outputs = []
        for feature in features:
            box_outputs.append(tf.reshape(self.box_head(feature), [N, -1, 4]))
            cls_outputs.append(
                tf.reshape(self.cls_head(feature), [N, -1, self.num_classes])
            )
        cls_outputs = tf.concat(cls_outputs, axis=1)
        box_outputs = tf.concat(box_outputs, axis=1)
        return tf.concat([box_outputs, cls_outputs], axis=-1)
    def get_config(self):
        return {"a": self.fpn, "b": self.num_classes, "c": self.cls_head,
                "d": self.box_head}
    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)
resnet50_backbone = get_backbone()
loss_fn = RetinaNetLoss(num_classes)
model = RetinaNet(num_classes, resnet50_backbone)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate_fn, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss=loss_fn, optimizer=optimizer)

callbacks_list = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=os.path.join(model_dir, "weights" + "_epoch_{epoch}"),
        monitor="loss",
        save_best_only=False,
        save_weights_only=True,
        verbose=1,
    )
]

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  model.fit(
      train_dataset.take(100),
      validation_data=val_dataset.take(50),
      epochs=epochs,
      callbacks=callbacks_list,
      verbose=1,
  )
'
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in `get_config` function which prevents the model from being serialized. In more detail: `{"a": self.var.numpy()}` will fail, as the model has no attribute `self.var`.

Comment: @sebastian-sz I corrected the mistake but still model.save is not a solution for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update the provided code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: @sebastian-sz done it!  Please check and tell me if any changes are required to be made

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure about custom subclassing and serialization. I can [link you](https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet/) keras example of this model which should serialize more easily. I know this is not much, but that's all I can come up with right now.

Comment: @sebastian-sz ok let's say that I use this model now the way it is loading the model for inference is still using keras.load_weights now I want to send it to somebody who doesn't have access to the model class how can we save this model?